# .nuspec file was removed and .nupkg file was created . Why?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, tfs, nuget

Am comparing 2 set of code in TFS between dev environment and another environment.The issue is, In dev enironment, file is missing like  below error message from TFS

> \packages\EntityFramework.5.0.0\EntityFramework.5.0.0.nuspec has a
>   pending add but does not exist locally

so, the same file with .nupkg extension was created instead of .nuspec.

1. may I know why .nupkg was came instead of .nuspec?
2. Also will it impact application execution?
3. If yes, How I can prevent?

Please answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the concept of nuget package , we build lot of custom nuget packages and this is how we use nuspec file.

To build a nuget package we need to create a .nuspec file ,this file will contain all the information about the package like name, version , all its dependent nuget package references , whether you need a source file for source server etc etc... Once this is ready we use this file to create the .nupkg file which is what actually nuget manager uses.

I don't know why you had .nuspec file in EntityFramework package may be a mistake , but you need not have to worry about the .nuspec file in your packages folder you just need .nupkg file.

**Long story short**, you don't need .nuspec file you just need .nupkg file and not have having .nuspec will not affect your project.